# Azure and node js __dirname

Tags: node.js, azure, webpack

Probably it is not specifically related to webpack/memory-fs, but I am getting the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error (see below for a call stack).

I have found out, that `__dirname` on Azure (webapp) returns `\\100.78.172.13\volume-7-default\8f5ecde749dace2bb57a\4e07195f015b45ce8e9ba255dc901988\site\repository\Source\Website\Content\app\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\normalize.js` in my situation, while `process.cwd()` returns `D:\home\site\repository\Source\Website\Content\app`.

Is anything can be done from my side to configure node js to return `D:\...` instead of `\\..` ?

[Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zygimantas/6d5fcb15547e84f5773f7b6226734737/raw/f37bd1a1ee46018413aa4cb24fc6187732314838/output.txt)

**How to reproduce:**

1. Clone the `https://github.com/intellismiths/webapp1` repository.
2. Create new Azure Web App (default settings).
3. Configure deployment source to use GitHub.
4. Click `Sync`. It will take 10+ minutes to complete and it will show that the deployment was successful.
5. Go to Application settings in Azure and change `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `6.2.2`
6. Go to kudu page and open powershell console.
7. Execute `npm cache clean`
8. Check node version by executing `node -v`. It should be `v6.2.2`
9. On Azure, navigate to `D:\home\site\respository\src\WebApp1`
10. Execute `npm run build`
11. **In console, you should see a lot of errors which indicates that modules can not be resolved**.
12. OPTIONAL. Test `npm run build` on your local machine - it should produce `wwwroot/app.js` without errors.
13. Update `webpack.config.js` to include `context: __dirname` to fix previous errors.
14. Execute `npm run build`
15. **In console, you should see the "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.**

**Update 1**

I only tried to set 6.2.2 runtime after adding the second package.json, so the project structure is not the simplest possible. Maybe just setting node to 6.2.2 breaks the build.

Comment: Could you please provide some key code snippets? As I cannot reproduce your issue on my side.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT 've just updated my question with code and instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue following your steps. I found the key point was setting the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `6.2.2`. And I found the webpack task worked fine if the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` was under `6`.

Please downgrade the setting `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to the version under `6` e.g. `5.9.0` if your node.js modules do not need such high version.
And according the `package.json` of angular2 athttps://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/package.json, it seems that the angular2 repository requires the node.js version between `5.4` and `6`.

Additionally, the web application's root directory on Azure Web Apps is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. So if you want to build your frontend project on Azure Web Apps, you need to locate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\mobile-web-app` then run `npm run build`.

Comment: Great suggestion for changing runtime to `5.9.0`. By the way, the only way I know to run `npm run build` in `modile-web-app` directory is to use npm run-script in `/wwwroot` directory (as in sample source code) which navigates to the `/mobile-web-app` directory and executes npm install and build scripts.Maybe you know, if there is any way to achieve the same without using "package.json" in `/wwwroot` directory? `prepublish` script in `Project.json` does not understand `cd` command directly.

Comment: Yes, the `package.json` in the `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\mobile-web-app` has already in the working folder, there is necessary to `cd` to `mobile-web-app`. And actually, the npm commands you configured in the `prepublish` in `project.json`  should be executed during the deployment task then you deploy your application to Azure. You can find the executing log during the deployment task the same as running command `npm run build` on KUDU.

Comment: You can find the deployment logs in KUDU at `D:\home\site\deployments`

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I have the same problem, but in my case I need Node 6+ - downgrading is not an option. I'm using webpack, but not Angular. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7294 - seems there was a change in Node somewhere around 6.2.1 that altered the behavior of `__dirname` for mounted network shares.

Answer (score 3):

It's been fixed in `master` and it's proposed to be included in `v6.4.0`.

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7175#issuecomment-239824532 and https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/8070

Answer (score 1):

After a long day of research, trial-and-error and various experimentation, I've found an acceptable workaround if you're *not* willing to downgrade to Node 5.*:

- Downgrade to Node 6.1.0
- Make sure to install webpack *globally* (with `npm install -g webpack`).

Just using 6.1.0 gets around the "maximum call stack size exceeded" error, but instead gave me a lot of resolve failures when running webpack from node_modules (using `./node_modules/.bin/webpack`). Installing webpack globally finally got me past that.

If I understand it correctly, this whole issue with `__dirname` in Node >= 6.2 resolving to the UNC folder path instead of the mounted path is going to be fixed, there's an active discussion [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7175).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
Fixed it with UPGRADING npm not DOWNGRADING.

Bug is fixed in the npm versions newer than 6.5.

https://github.com/aumanjoa/chronas-community/blob/master/package.json#L48

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your __dirname shows your persistant drive where the data is stored, while .cwd gives current directory from where node ran. This is because Azure runs from the Drive but files are stored at the persistent drive.

In your Gruntfile.js add

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {  
  grunt.file.setBase(__dirname);  
  // Code omitted  
}
```

Refer: [link](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx)

Comment: I have seen this link, no I am not using Grunt.