# Issue running Node app on Azure App Service with engines greater than 6.0.0

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

There seems to be an Azure issue running Node apps with engines greater than 6.0.0.

It comes up with an error similar to the following:

```
Error: Not Found
at \\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\config\express.js:36:15
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at \\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at methodOverride (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\method-override\index.js:65:14)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (\\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at \\100.72.114.39\volume-10-default\bc07ff16757397422510\c76bdd71a9f84626a73576980337b6ce\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/)
2. Site runs normally with no `engines` specified (defaults to 4.2.3 as of this post)
3. Change the `engines` field to `6.2.2` or `6.3.0` --> fails.

FYI it runs OK with `6.0.0`

Comment: Can you please share a test repo, per [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue)? Thanks!

Comment: Sure no problems.. it's here: https://github.com/lyphtec/azure-node-test

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue with you on SO, [Azure and node js __dirname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173996/azure-and-node-js-dirname/38197085#38197085).

And relate to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7294, it seems that there was a change which altered the behavior of __dirname for mounted network shares when the Node.js version higher than 6.2.x .

Currently, the workaround is to downgrade the node.js version to the version under 6.2 in your Azure Web App.

Comment: Ah that explains it. I was able to repro with @LyphTEC's test repo above. Hopefully they'll fix that in Node soon.