# keystone deployment fails on azure

Tags: azure, keystonejs, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure web-app and deploying my keystone app to azure from github.
Unfortunately I end up in an 500 error:

```
Tue May 23 2017 19:36:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\C:\DWASFiles\Sites\chronasWebApp\DynamicCache\wwwroot\routes\api'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:945:18)
    at importer (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\chronasWebApp\DynamicCache\wwwroot\node_modules\keystone\lib\core\importer.js:32:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\chronasWebApp\DynamicCache\wwwroot\routes\index.js:37:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\chronasWebApp\DynamicCache\wwwroot\keystone.js:59:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

How knows what the issue is?
This is the app we deploy: 
https://github.com/aumanjoa/chronas-community

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "chronas",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/daumann/chronas-community.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "browserify-middleware": "^7.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.5",
    "graphql": "^0.9.6",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "keystone": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone.git#f3083c",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "log4js": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "newrelic": "^1.39.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "store-prototype": "^1.1.1",
    "superagent": "^3.5.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2",
    "npm": "3.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node keystone.js",
    "print-graphql-schema": "babel-node ./graphql/scripts/printSchema.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was related to this bug 
[Azure and node js __dirname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173996/azure-and-node-js-dirname)

fixed the issue by updating to new node version.

```
"node": "6.10.0",
"npm": "3.10.10"
```